# Android-PHP Encoded String with RSA passed to PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption, rsa, urlconnection

I know it could be easier with https connection, but for the university project there is no money for that. We have an Apache2 Webserver, but are not able to include a certificate due to permission restrictions. URL Connection with sending the data is correct so I did not include it to my question, so the problem is with formatting or de-/encryption.

So the base Idea is: Generate a own Certificate with openssl. Encrypt the Data on Android, send with UrlConnection to the server, there it has to be decrypted to perform more operations.

Android Encryption:

```
    AssetManager assetManager=activity.getAssets();
    InputStream in=assetManager.open("certificate.crt");
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(in);
    PublicKey publicServerKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicServerKey);
    byte[] parametersCipher = cipher.doFinal(parameters.getBytes());
    String encoded=new String(Base64.encode(parametersCipher, Base64.DEFAULT));
    String parametersencrypted="data="+URLEncoder.encode(encoded,"UTF-8");
```

The String parametersencrypted will be send with POST Data to the Server
Now the Server Part:
PHP Decryption:

```
$data=utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['data']));    
$privateKey=openssl_pkey_get_private("file://certificate.key", "password");
$data = base64_decode($data);
openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted,$privateKey);
```

The Server is getting the Base64 Encoded String, but the decryption String is empty.  If I encrypt a String in php I am able to decrypt it, same on Android, I think the problem is with the formatting for HTTP Request with UTF-8 Urlencoding or so, but I am not getting a solution for it.
Please help me to solve this specific problem.

### **UPDATE**

Ok I did got it working with Java, but not on Android:
Java Code:

```
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicServerKey);
byte[] parametersCipher = cipher.doFinal(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String encoded=new String(encoder.encode(parametersCipher)); //encoder= base64 encoder 
encoded=encoded.replace("+", "-");
encoded=encoded.replace("/", "_");
```

Modified PHP:

```
$data = base64_decode(strtr($string, '-_', '+/')); 
openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, $this->privateKey,OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
```

Android Code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicServerKey);
byte[] parametersCipher = cipher.doFinal(parameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String encoded=new String(Base64.encode(parametersCipher, Base64.URL_SAFE)); //URL_SAFE from Android Documentation + as - and / as _
String parametersencrypted="data="+encoded;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have already encoded to `Base64` then after that you encode to `utf-8` why is that?

Comment: As far as I know Base64 could contain characters that are not safe for http request. But I am not sure

Comment: Base 64 (Radix 64) : MIME `Base64` :  "A–Z", "a–z", "0–9", plus two more characters, often "+" and "/". I think it was invented specifically to be transported over networks, the binary data represented as string will create those funny character.

Comment: Try and use url safe base 64 (search for rfc base64url), you can create it by simply removing all newlines and replacing the + and /.

Comment: thanks, I am now using url safe base, but my problem is not completely gone. I updated my Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With updated code I put the wrong certificate to the app. Now it is working.